# Can I manually trigger the rendering of template fields of a custom Operator in Airflow?

Tags: airflow

I am using Airflow 1.10.12 and have a PythonOperator task which is defined like the following:

```
        task = PythonOperator(task_id=task_id,
                          op_kwargs=instance,
                          provide_context=True,
                          python_callable=execute_request,
                          dag=MY_DAG)
```

I execute another (custom) Operator Within the function `execute_request`:

```
    glue_operator = GlueCatalogUpdateOperator(data_path=s3_partition_path,
                                          catalog_mapping=
                                          get_google_sheet_catalog(r_table,
                                                                   r_db,
                                                                   s3_table_path),
                                          dag=None, task_id='none')
    glue_operator.execute(None)
```

The problem is, that I have defined some `template_fields` in `GlueCatalogUpdateOperator` and these don't get rendered. If I create a task defined as `GlueCatalogUpdateOperator` it works. I assume it's because I am directly calling `execute` and template rendering happens typically before the execution - is this correct?

Is there a way to trigger the rendering or manually render templated fields?

**Edit**
I am able to pass the context via

```
glue_operator.execute(context=context)
```

However, templated fields still don't get rendered.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Technically, yes. For example:

```py
import datetime

from airflow import DAG
from airflow.operators.bash import BashOperator
from airflow.operators.python import PythonOperator


def _test_templating(**context):
    # This will literally echo "Today is {{ ds_nodash }}."
    BashOperator(task_id="whatever_name", bash_command="echo 'Today is {{ ds_nodash }}.'").execute(
        context=context
    )

    # This will echo e.g. "Today is 20230101."
    test = BashOperator(task_id="whatever_name", bash_command="echo 'Today is {{ ds_nodash }}.'")
    test.render_template_fields(context=context)
    test.execute(context={})


with DAG("test_templating", start_date=datetime.datetime(2023, 1, 1), schedule_interval="@daily") as dag:
    task = PythonOperator(task_id="test_templating", python_callable=_test_templating)
```

The task instance `context` is passed to the `_test_templating` function (line 8). The `context` is then passed along when calling the method `render_template_fields` (line 16), which renders templated fields given the `context` on the BashOperator.

A few notes:

- The question feels like the result of a workaround. I assume you're doing more than just calling the GlueCatalogUpdateOperator from inside a PythonOperator callable as shown in your question? If not, there's no need to and it adds unnecessary complexity. Would call the GlueCatalogUpdateOperator directly.
- Code was tested on Airflow 2.5.0. There's a `render_template_fields` method on the `BaseOperator` in Airflow 1.10.12: https://github.com/apache/airflow/blob/6416d898060706787861ff8ecbc4363152a35f45/airflow/models/baseoperator.py#L705-L719, so I assume the code above also works in Airflow 1.10.12 (note: Airflow 1 requires `provide_context=True` on PythonOperators to pass context).
- Airflow 1.10.12 has been end-of-life for a year and a half now (see https://endoflife.date/apache-airflow and https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow/stable/installation/supported-versions.html), I strongly suggest upgrading to Airflow 2.